# What is the way to persist a trie data tree with 27000 nodes in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistence, trie

I am building a Trie tree that will have about 27000 of the nodes below.  Instead of recreating it every time on app start, I would like to persist.  Because the child property is a dictionary to another node, I'm having trouble using `NSCoding` to archive and store it in the core data entity.  Is there a way to store this node in Core Data?  Or should I be using a different type of persistence?

```
class TrieNode {

    var letter:Character
    var fullWord:Bool
    var leadingLetters:String
    var child = [Character:TrieNode]()

    init (letter:Character, leadingLetters:String, fullWord:Bool) {
        self.letter = letter
        self.fullWord = fullWord
        self.leadingLetters = leadingLetters
    }
}
```

The main problem I had in trying to use Core Data is how to convert `var child = [Character:TrieNode]()` into NSData or another useable type that CD can store in an entity. Examples on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to store it as `NSData`. Just create the data model for the `TrieNode` and make a `NSManagedObject` of it.

Comment: And then how do I store the child property? It won't let me compile `[Character:TrieNode]()` as an `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Please just look into Core Data. It's appreciated if you put some effort in it yourself. This site isn't here to educate you on his to use it, but to help you with specific problems.

Comment: This site is to provide help and guidance @GuidoHendriks - you are welcome to attempt to help if you don't know the answer. I presented you with a specific problem - I could not find a way to store `[Character:TrieNode]()` as an `NSManagedObject` which is what led to the top question to begin with.  Are you willing to further clarify your suggestion?  Thank you.

Comment: That's just a basic one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward in Core Data. I think what I'd do is:

1. Create a new entity called something like `TrieNodeLink`. It has one property, a string called something like `childString` and one relationship, called `node` of type `TrieNode`. Each instance of this entity represents one single sub-node of a trie node.
2. Add a new to-many relationship from your existing `TrieNode` to the new `TrieNodeLink` entity.
3. Keep your existing `child` dictionary. At a convenient time, initialize this dictionary by scanning the new to-many relationship from step 2. A convenient time might be in `awakeFromFetch`, or else you could make it a Swift `lazy` property. Or if you want to pre-load data for faster performance at the cost of higher memory use, you might write some code to recursively load child nodes a few levels deep before they're needed.

The effect of this would be that you'd load portions of the trie on demand, when needed. Once loaded you'd be able to use your `child` dictionary to quickly look up child nodes.

Comment: Thank you Tom.  My main problem is trying to turn the child dictionary into something core data likes - do you have any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: I think I just described one approach. You can't save the dictionary, so you need to convert to/from something that can be saved in Core Data. This is one scheme; there are probably others.