# Folder structure in core data

Tags: ios, macos, sqlite, core-data

I am storing folder structure in core data. Its reflecting local structure of files/folders and need to update DB whenever user perform any operation in finder(e.g. rename/delete/create).

I have defined single entity node(name, fullPath, type(dir/ file)).
a *to-many* relationship `children` from the node entity to itself, with the delete rule set to cascade
a *to-one* relationship `parent` from the node entity to itself, with the delete rule set to nullify.
and set these as inverse relationships of each other.

I am having issue when user rename folder. Currently I am updating node and added method to construct full path via parent path and child name.

But sometimes I need to fetch node via path and file nodes are not updated after rename. I don’t want to loop over all files inside folder after rename. Some folder contain 100k nodes.

Can anyone please help me out or suggest me better design ?

Comment: Why are you storing the full path on every node?

Comment: @TomHarrington This was old code. We had flat structure of all files/folder. Now I have added parent child relationship but I am still facing same problem when user rename folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created this problem and now you're seeing its effects.

- You store the full path on every node
- You have nodes with 100k or more sub-nodes
- You want to be able to rename arbitrary parts of the path

No matter how you store the data, you've created a situation where it may become necessary to update string values on 100k or more nodes at once. That's a lot of work and it's not easily optimized, because sooner or later you have to calculate and update all of those strings.

So the real question is, why are you storing the full path on every node and can you manage to stop doing that?

I'm not sure why you're doing it. For every node, you can work out the path by recursively following parent relationships until you reach the root node. Likewise, if you have a full path and need to find the node, you can split the path into components using the path delimiter (probably "`/`") and then work your way down from the root node via child relationships to get the target node.

The nice thing about this is that if you rename a node somewhere in the middle of the tree, that's it, you're done! No need to update any other nodes.

It might be better to represent the data as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of simply naming each node and linking its child nodes, but that takes some creativity in Core Data. I described [one possible approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574598/43832) a while ago but I don't necessarily claim it's the best one. I wouldn't try this unless you find the approach I describe above to be slow in practice.

Comment: I can store only node name but fetching node using full path will take more time if parent have 10k node. I need to check node till I get matching child  and repeat same step for child nodes.

Comment: I understand that. Your requirements are going to need a lot of work if you use this kind of structure, which is why I mentioned the idea of a trie. I'd try the approach above first though, because although 10k sounds like a lot, that doesn't necessarily mean it's too slow for your app.

Comment: One more solution when I get full path. Split the path into components using path delimiter and then fetch all node with matching name and remove false nodes by comparing relationship.

Comment: @ParagBafna Good idea!